# Cypress log in with oauth and cy.session

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I have the following scenario
My home page is https://home.domain.dev/auth/login, on that page I have a button to Continue
After clicking on Continue it redirects to this page https://sso.domain.dev/oauth2/xxxxxxx
On that page, I have the login form, where I can enter the email and password and click on Log in
After logging in, it redirects to https://home.domain.dev/onboarding
https://home.domain.dev/onboarding/business

(I have tried many things, that's why I have that code commented)
I'm trying this but it doesn't work, because after logging in, it redirects to the auth page again.

How can I log in via UI in this scenario?
Before I used Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce

[image]
[image]